# She was forced ... torture to testify that. What preposition to put in the blank?

Tags: single-word-requests, prepositions

> She was forced ... torture to testify that.

What preposition is the best choice for the blank? Different suggestion, such as *by*, *under*, and *with* can be find in the [literature](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=forced%20by%20torture%20to%2Cforced%20under%20torture%20to%2C%20forced%20with%20torture%20to%2C%20forced%20through%20torture%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cforced%20by%20torture%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cforced%20under%20torture%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cforced%20through%20torture%20to%3B%2Cc0), which *by* being the most common, it sounds like *under* is the most idiomatic. What do you think?

Comment: Was torture *doing* the forcing? Or was torture used to force?

Comment: Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+forced+*+torture&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cwas%20forced%20%2A%20torture%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwas%20forced%20under%20torture%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwas%20forced%20by%20torture%3B%2Cc0), ***under*** has become significantly more common than ***by*** over the past century, for your exact context. To my ear, ***with*** sounds strange/dated (and it doesn't occur often enough to show on that chart). But grammatically, there's nothing wrong with any of them (or ***through, using***, etc.).

Comment: @marcellothearcane How are they different?

Comment: Perhaps also consider [_via_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/via)?

Comment: If it was just the tool (if it was used) then I think you'd use 'under'. Otherwise 'by'.